# Can you help me understand this C++ template code? 

Tags: c++, templates

Hya,

Can anyone please tell me how this thing is working?

```
template <typename T,
template <typename ELEM> class CONT = std::deque >
class Stack {
private:
CONT<T> elems; // elements

public:
void push(T const&); // push element
void pop(); // pop element
T top() const; // return top element
bool empty() const { // return whether the stack is empty
return elems.empty();
}
};
```

What i don't understand is this :
template class V or say this "template  class CONT = std::deque"

i visualize this as

```
template <class>
class CONT = std::deque // here CONT is templatized class declaration.
```

but what pesters me is , how can we assign something to class name CONT , rather than writing its definition (which i've done till this time):

```
template <class>
class CONT{
//def
}
```

one more thing :

```
template <class> // why its only class written in angle bracket there should be also be name
like : template<class ty>
```

Thanks a lot , any help is very appreciated)

Comment: **This will not work.** `std::deque` takes two arguments (one is optional) and therefore can only be passed as a `template` template parameter with **two** arguments. Here you can pass `std::deque<T>` (and not `std::deque`) as a normal template parameter: this is how `std::stack` works. In general, template template parameters are not flexible enough to be worth the trouble using them (except perhaps in metaprogramming contexts).

Comment: Your code has a multitude of syntax errors. I fixed just one.

Comment: @Tomalak: yes it does, but you made it worse.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Ah sorry, yes I did. Parse failure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i don't understand is this : template class V

There is no such line in your question, so I can't help with that.

```
template< template <typename ELEM> class CONT = std::deque >
class Stack
```

This is a declaration of a template template parameter. You pass a template into the `Stack` template, and then `Stack` can use it internally.

The `= std::deque` part is a default value, in case you leave the CONT parameter unspecified. (`std::deque` is a predefined template.)

However, this will not work, because `std::deque` takes two arguments. This will work:

```
template< template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC> class CONT = std::deque >
class Stack
```

However `ELEM` and `ALLOC` do not actually name anything; they exist merely to clarify what the parameter list of the required template is. So, you can omit them:

```
template< template <typename, typename> class CONT = std::deque >
class Stack
```

Comment: Can you explain in deep and in more basic form after line "What i don't understand is this : template class V or say this "template class CONT = std::deque" . Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an object assignment. It's just syntax in a template specifier to specify what the default type argument should be if one is not provided. It's *not* a definition for that type.

Comment: What he said. So `CONT` is the second template parameter for `Stack`, and `CONT` is itself a template class, and finally the default value for `CONT` is `std::deque`.

Comment: @Ilkka: Yes, though `CONT` being a template class is one of the syntax errors in the OP's code, as he doesn't actually treat it as such.

Comment: Yeah, I was too weak in the force to detect that one without throwing it at a compiler. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @Ilkka: The force is still strong in you. :)